# Is there a way to have a function for a implementation for a struct that moves self instead of borrowing it as &self or &mut self?

Tags: rust

I have been dealing with this because I want to create a style of configuration that is somewhat of functional as it would be used like:

```rust
struct.set_config(myConfig)
      .set_other_config(myOtherConfig)
```

And to do this I need to return a owned version of the struct or another type that is similar to it in my case.

And to do this I would actually need to borrow that into a implemented function of that struct. My thought would be that it would look something like:

```rust
impl MyStruct {
  fn set_config(self, ...) -> Self {
    (...do something with self)

    self // return the mutated self
  }
}
```

But when trying something similar to this the Rust compiler did not like that very much.

Is there any way to kind of implement this? Or at least another way to get what I want without this?

EDIT:

My problem with just adding "mut self" is the Rust compiler seemed to complain with a warning:

```
warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
    = note: for more information, see issue #35203 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35203>
    = note: `#[deny(patterns_in_fns_without_body)]` on by default
```

And I wanted to avoid that. This error originates in the trait that defines that function not in the implementation.

EDIT 2:

I am working on a Machine Learning crate and I have layers for a Model, there is a Layer trait and I want to have Initializers for instantiating the parameters depending on how the user wants to initialize them.

Another important thing is that I have a enum that can be all of the layers currently implemented in the crate, this enum has that same trait implemented and each method has a match for each possible type of Layer.

Currently in the crate, to define the layers for a model you currently need to do something like:

```rust
let layers = vec![
  Dense::new(...),
  TanH::new(...)
];
```

(The "new" method returns that enum that has all the implemented layers as variants)

I want to set the initializers (which are now a field of these layers's structs) as such:

```rust
let layers = vec![
  Dense::new(...).set_initializer(...),
  TanH::new(...)
];
```

Then the set_initializer would need to return that enum owning the Dense layer for example. Hence my problem.

The important part of my Layer trait definition would need to look like this:

```rust
pub trait Layer<'a> {
    (...)

    fn set_initializer(mut self, initializer: Initializer) -> ModelLayer<'a>; // This is the enum I mentioned

    (...)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a very common builder pattern. Can you elaborate on *"But when trying something similar to this the Rust compiler did not like that very much"*?

Comment: Please provide a specific complete example and the actual compiler error message.

Comment: Taking `self` and returning `self` is just how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps you've missed that you can do `mut self` (no `&`) to take ownership and allow mutations?

Comment: Don't put the `mut` if there's no body (like in a trait definition). You can have it in the implementations.

Comment: @lurker Added an edit with some more info to the question

Comment: @kmdreko So how should I go about adding something like this into the trait? I think I have a way around this compiler error that would perhaps be a bit cleaner now that I am thinking about it. But is there a way anyways just for the sake of the question?

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible example that you're having troubles with. It seems there is a lot of miscommunication in these comments and having code to build from will help dispell confusion. The snippets you posted don't have traits involved like your comments/warning suggest. What you're asking for is very common and easily done in Rust, so it seems the trouble is just semantics and/or syntax.

Comment: @kmdreko Added an edit with some more explanation of my code and some examples

Comment: You still have not given the code that caused the error you included.

Comment: @PitaJ Sorry, just added it

Comment: All you have to do to avoid that error is change all `mut self` to just `self` in the trait definition. You can still use it when implementing the trait.

Comment: @PitaJ That actually solves it, can you summarize that in a answer for me to close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pattern_in_fns_without_body` error triggers on `mut self` parameters in body-less function signatures. This includes functions without bodies in trait definitions.

All you need to do to resolve the error is change `mut self` to just `self` in your trait definition:

```rust
pub trait Layer<'a> {
    // ...

    fn set_initializer(self, initializer: Initializer) -> ModelLayer<'a>;

    // ...
}
```

This restriction only applies to body-less functions. Your actual trait implementation can still have the `mut self` if necessary:

```rust
impl<'a> Layer<'a> for SomeThing<'a> {
    // ...

    fn set_initializer(mut self, initializer: Initializer) -> ModelLayer<'a> {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'm not sure what version of Rust you're working with, but recent versions of the compiler have a hint recommending just that:

```
error: patterns aren't allowed in functions without bodies
 --> src/lib.rs:7:24
  |
7 |     fn set_initializer(mut self, initializer: Initializer) -> ModelLayer<'a>;
  |                        ^^^^^^^^ help: remove `mut` from the parameter: `self`
  |
  = warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
  = note: for more information, see issue #35203 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35203>
  = note: `#[deny(patterns_in_fns_without_body)]` on by default
```